# Woocommerce 2.4x - Variable price issue using 2.0 from price method

Tags: variables, woocommerce

Before 2.4x I used this snippet to get From price instead of min-max price on the catalog and on the product pages.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'From: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
$price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
}
return $price;
}
```

But since they updated the whole variation logic it doesn't seem to work so good any more. I refer to this official post: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/caching-and-dynamic-pricing-upcoming-changes-to-the-get_variation_prices-method/

Any tips how this fix this?

Reference:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.4.7/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L257

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how WooCommerce is [generating the variable price html](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.4.7/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L374). That should help a lot. Based on that, here's what I've come up with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'so_32738056_filter_variable_price_html', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'so_32738056_filter_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );

function so_32738056_filter_variable_price_html( $price, $product ){
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
    $max_price = end( $prices['price'] );
    $price     = $min_price !== $max_price ? sprintf( _x( 'From %1$s', 'minimum price', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) ) : wc_price( $min_price );
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $min_regular_price = current( $prices['regular_price'] );
        $max_regular_price = end( $prices['regular_price'] );
        $regular_price     = $min_regular_price !== $max_regular_price ? sprintf( _x( 'From: %1$s', 'minimum price', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_regular_price ), wc_price( $max_regular_price ) ) : wc_price( $min_regular_price );
        $price             = '<del>' . $regular_price . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
    } else {
        $price = $price . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }   
    return $price;
}
```